# how to set column property NOT NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

I need to set my column property to NOT NULL, but I'm not able to set the property it produces the below error..

**MY Query:**

```
ALTER TABLE CartReceBenif
ALTER COLUMN RecipientId int NOT NULL;
```

[image]

**ERROR**

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'RecipientId', table 'test.dbo.CartReceBenif'; column does not
>   allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The statement has been terminated.

Can any one suggest what is the mistake..

Comment: You can't do that if you already have `NULL` values in that column. Is that the case?

Comment: You must use add constraints clause in order to add a constraints in your table.

Comment: make sure that your "RecipientId" column not exist with null record. possible then remove all record of table and apply ALTER Table query.

Comment: Add a default constraint for the same and check if it is containing some Null values or update the null values with any default value and check.

Comment: Thank-You.. @Rachit Patel and Azar , shree.part18.. my db had null value so it dosent work.. now it works fine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible data present in this table and null values in this column. Try to update table, set values in this column to 1 for example before altering. Or just remove all data from the table before altering.